# Qtdatetime creating problems when using Qtcore

Tags: qt

I was trying to implement threading in a program so I included "Qt core" header but while compiling I m getting errors as below :

```
D:\QT\5.0.2\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qdatetime.h
error: C2589: '(' : illegal token on right side of '::'
```

when I remove qtcore header it works,what should I do?

Comment: You don't normally include `QtCore` in the code yourself, usually it's in the `.pro` file so `qmake` pulls it in.  Can we see your `.pro` file?

Comment: What is the actual `include` statement you're using? Another thing you can do is check for syntax errors in header files you've included before this one.

Comment: Problem solved.I used Qtcore/Qthread instead of whole Qtcore as I needed only QThread.